# GIT: Why every time I git push to production, database got cleaned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Every time I run the `git push` after modifying some codes and try to display app, the following `no such table` error appeared.

stdout.log (production environment)

```
Started GET "/" for 111.222.333.444 at 2014-11-13 22:07:36 +0900
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: articles: SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"   ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: articles: SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"   ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

The procedure I did is described below.

```
rake aseets:precompile
git add .
git commit -m "xxx"
git checkout master
git merge xxx    #branch name
git push origin master
```

I execute the following commands at a hosting service (not heroku) because the error message mentioned above were displayed.

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

Does it means that all the data stored was cleaned every time I execute `git push`?
Please advise me on how to keep the data if I run git push.

Answer (score 3):

Like most PaaS providers, Heroku [does not provide a persistent filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Each time you deploy, any files that you have stored locally will be lost.

The general recommendation for file storage on Heroku is to [use something like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3), which will let you store files across deploys. But if you can get away from SQLite, you should consider simply migrating to PostgreSQL, which is [natively supported by Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), or another database by using one of the [supported data storage addons](https://addons.heroku.com/#data-stores).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Chris. The root cause of this problem was the wrong settings in `config\database.yml`. It works after deleting `host: mysql001.xxx.com` despite the existence of `adapter: sqlite3`.